# I need to calculate percentage from score using a SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

Currently I am getting output for score as " 25 / 50 " as string through SQL, now I need to calculate percentage from this score and return that value using a SQL statement in Post Gres SQL.

```
SELECT es.score FROM emp_scores es WHERE id = 123;
```

This returns me a string as " 25 / 50 ". Now I want to calculate the percentage from this string.

Comment: Is it stored in the database as `25 / 50`?

Comment: You can do it in sql with substring and convert but these kind of operations are usually easier to do on a higher level.

Comment: You should not save those values in one and the same column. Split them into two columns if there are only two teams in each match. Or create a new table for the scores having an 1:n connection to it, to track more than two teams and their scores for one match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to split your data first then you can calculate percentage...
you can use

```
    split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)  
   //Split string on delimiter and return the given field (counting from one)
```

here is example

```
SELECT (CAST(coalesce(split_part(es.score,'/',2)*100), '0') AS integer)*100)/CAST(coalesce(split_part(es.score,'/',1)*100), '0') AS integer) as 'Percentage' FROM emp_scores es WHERE id = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
cast(substring(es.score,0,patindex('%/%',es.score)) as int)/
cast(substring(es.score
       ,patindex('%/%',es.score)+1
       ,len(es.score)-patindex('%/%',es.score)) as int)*100
FROM emp_scores es WHERE id = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using cte

```
create table emp_scores (
   gid serial primary key,
   score varchar
);
insert into emp_scores values (123,  ' 25 / 50 ');

with t as (
    select regexp_split_to_array(' 25 / 50 ', '/') scores from emp_scores where gid = 123
)
select 100 * scores[1]::real / scores[2]::real from t;
```